# Setting bitmap as content icon in wearable notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I am using below code to generate notification in the wear.

```
new Notification.WearableExtender()
.setBackground(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.example_big_picture))
                     .setContentIcon(R.drawable.image)
                     .setContentIconGravity(Gravity.START))
```

But `setContentIcon` can be used to set only drawable images. Is there any way to set `bitmap` as content icon (I am getting the bitmap from server). Or is there any other way to achieve the same result? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

convert the bitmap to a drawable

```html
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmaphere);
```